# Can district ziputils ANE zip files/folders?

Tags: distriqt

wondering if the district ziputils ANE can be used to zip files/folder, not just unzip them

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently the ANE can only be used to unzip files. We use it mainly for deploying assets to devices.

If you have a feature request feel free to drop it on our suggestion site:

https://distriqt.uservoice.com